# 「manlen (0,0) p == n」の解釈について

Tags: haskell

```
manlen p1 p2 = abs(fst p1 - fst p2) + abs(snd p1 - snd p2)
points n = [(x,y) | x <- [-n .. n], y <- [-n .. n]]
mancircle n = [p | p <- points n, manlen (0,0) p == n]
```

最後のリスト内包表記内の、`manlen (0,0) p == n`がよくわかりません。
manlen の引数に p == nを取っているのはなぜなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

haskell では `==` のような両側に引数を取る infix の演算子の優先順位は、普通の関数呼び出しより低いです。したがって `manlen (0,0) p == n` は `manlen (0,0) (p == n)` ではなく`(manlen (0,0) p) == n`と解釈されます。これは Bool を返すのでフィルターになります。従って

```
mancircle n = [p | p <- points n, manlen (0,0) p == n]
```

は、`points n`の要素の中で`manlen (0,0) p`が n になるものだけを返します。